# how to get current skin url in magento?

Tags: php, magento, skin, static-block

I am using Magento 1.9.2.4.
I am using static block for my custom themes and i give the path for images

```
<img alt="" src="{{skin url=’homepage/images/visa.png’}}" />
```

but it's return

```
http://mydomain/skin/frontend/base/default/’homepage/images/visa.png
```

not my current themes path.
I am new magento. Please someone guide me.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

Go to magento admin panel
System >> Configuration

Go to 
GENERAL >> Design 
 add your Package and Themes name

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found my mistake

```
<img alt="" src="{{skin url=’homepage/images/visa.png’}}" />
```

I remove '' in skin url

```
<img alt="" src="{{skin url=homepage/images/visa.png}}" />
```

now it's working for me.